# Reload SSL context used by Spring Kafka at runtime

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

What is the recommended way to make Spring Kafka reload SSL context?

I have a requirement to insert new certificates into the trust store that my Kafka producer uses without any downtime.

However what I have found is that once the application is started and a Kafka producer is created, [an instance of SSLContext is created and cached](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/common/security/ssl/SslFactory.java#L141). There [is a way to reconfigure](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/common/security/ssl/SslFactory.java#L168) this but the only way I have found so far is to destroy any existing producers by [invoking the destroy method on `DefaultKafkaProducerFactory`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/blob/master/spring-kafka/src/main/java/org/springframework/kafka/core/DefaultKafkaProducerFactory.java#L219) (after certificate renewal) which causes any subsequent calls to `KafkaTemplate.send` to force a new producer to be created which in turn reloads the SSL context.

I feel this is like using a sledgehammer to solve this problem and there might be a more elegant solution. I have also noticed that if I call destroy when there are messages being sent, I get the below exception which doesn't look very positive when we cannot afford to lose any events.

```
java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Producer closed while send in progress
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:273)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:280)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run$$$capture(CompletableFuture.java:1592)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.exec(CompletableFuture.java:1582)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Producer closed while send in progress
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.doSend(KafkaProducer.java:826)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.send(KafkaProducer.java:803)
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory$CloseSafeProducer.send(DefaultKafkaProducerFactory.java:444)
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate.doSend(KafkaTemplate.java:372)
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate.send(KafkaTemplate.java:190)
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaOperations$send.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.example.event.publisher.kafka.KafkaEventPublisher.doPublish(KafkaEventPublisher.groovy:57)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:98)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:352)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1034)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:68)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:177)
    at com.example.event.publisher.kafka.KafkaEventPublisher$_publish_closure1.doCall(KafkaEventPublisher.groovy:47)
    at com.example.event.publisher.kafka.KafkaEventPublisher$_publish_closure1.doCall(KafkaEventPublisher.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:98)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:264)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1034)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:418)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ConvertedClosure.invokeCustom(ConvertedClosure.java:54)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ConversionHandler.invoke(ConversionHandler.java:124)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy103.get(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run$$$capture(CompletableFuture.java:1590)
    ... 6 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Requested metadata update after close
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata.awaitUpdate(Metadata.java:200)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.waitOnMetadata(KafkaProducer.java:938)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.doSend(KafkaProducer.java:823)
    ... 37 common frames omitted
```

Comment: i have this similar situation. There were some discussions regarding this in official defects section (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-4701). Do you happen to have any solution?

Answer (score 2):

Spring Kafka 2.6.5, Kafka 2.4.1, I use KafkaProducerFactory.reset() instead.

```
@Autowired
private final KafkaTemplate<String, byte[]> kafkaTemplate;


private void reloadProducer() {
    kafkaTemplate.getProducerFactory().reset();
}
```

Next time send() is called, Spring will recreate a brand spanking new KafkaConsumer with the new certificate.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like simply resetting the config for certain values will trigger a rebuild on the SSL engine factory. They even call out file key config that would cause a hot reload.

[link](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/462c89e0b436abd56864bea8bbcaf1ab70b7f66e/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/common/security/auth/SslEngineFactory.java#L70)

Comment: The shouldBeRebuild is part of Kafka Dynamic Configuration. That's a broker side feature and there is no practical way to instantiate it client side. (https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/kafka/dynamic-config.html)